# Test for containment with a series of tuples

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.Series` of tuples:

```
s = pd.Series([('a','b','c'), ('a','c','b'), ('c','a','b')])
```

and I want to check whether `('a','b','c')` is in `s` (or any other tuple). So:

```
('a', 'b', 'c') in s
```

returns `False`. However,

```
('a', 'b', 'c') in s.tolist()
```

returns, as expected, `True`. Is there an optimized, pandas' way, of doing it? It feels very non-pythonic to convert to a list.

Comment: A Series is like a dictionary. When you use `something in s`  you are checking for its index (equivalently, `something in d`  checks for dictionary's keys). If you want to check its values, you need to use `something in s.values`. However, it seems numpy doesn't support checking against tuples so it returns False.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `equal` operation to create a `bool` series then use `any()` to get the desired result. Or as a more comprehensive approach you can use `apply()` method of the series objects in order to apply a specific function on all items. Then you can use `any()` to get the expected result:

```
In [28]: (s == ('a', 'b', 'c')).any()
Out[28]: True

In [30]: s.apply(('a', 'b', 'c').__eq__).any()
Out[30]: True
```

Also note that since `Series` is a One-dimensional ndarray with axis labels the membership checking with `in` operator will be performed on indices rather than the items.

```
In [32]: 3 in s
Out[32]: False

In [33]: 2 in s
Out[33]: True
```

In case you want to change this behavior you might want to override the `__contains__` method of the object by creating your own `Series` type.

```
In [39]: class MySeries(pd.Series):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySeries, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def __contains__(self, arg):
        return (self == arg).any()            
   ....:     

In [40]: ms = MySeries([('a','b','c'), ('a','c','b'), ('c','a','b')])

In [41]: ('a', 'b', 'c') in ms
Out[41]: True

In [42]: 

In [42]: ('a', 'b', 't') in ms
Out[42]: False
```

You can also make it work for both indices and items:

```
In [51]: class MySeries(pd.Series):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySeries, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def __contains__(self, arg):
        if isinstance(arg, int):
            return super(MySeries, self).__contains__(arg)
        return (self == arg).any()
   ....:     

In [52]: 

In [52]: ms = MySeries([('a','b','c'), ('a','c','b'), ('c','a','b')])

In [53]: 

In [53]: 3 in ms
Out[53]: False

In [54]: 2 in ms
Out[54]: True

In [55]: 

In [55]: ('a', 'b', 'c') in ms
Out[55]: True

In [56]: ('a', 'b', 'd') in ms
Out[56]: False
```

Comment: I find this answer very comprehensive, as it explains the reason why the `in` operator behaves the way it does in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an equality check (`==`) and the `any` method:

```
(s == ('a', 'b', 'c')).any()
```

However that way you lose the short-circuit behavior that `in` provides.